# LPC1114 bootloader-polling and user app-interrupts

Tags: arm, bootloader, cortex-m

Keil UV4 Dev System, LPC1114
Running bootloader: 0x0000.0000-0x0000.2000, user app: 0x0000.2000-0x0000.6000

Question - How to configure for Bootloader using polling and User App using interrupts

I have been referring to NXP appnote 10995, and re-direction of interrupts, however- in this situation the bootloader does not use interrupts, and the user app does.  When the user app generates an interrupt, the LPC114 interrupt vector is located in sector 0 (bootloader).

I understand the interrupt vector located at sector 0 must somehow redirect to an interrupt handler located at 0x0000.2000, but does interrupt code still need to be included in the bootloader to allow a redirect function from the interrupt handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interrupt vectors will still be defined for your bootloader in the startup file (startup_LPC11xx.s), even if your bootloader does not utilize them.  At a minimum, the initial stack pointer value, reset vector, NMI vector and Hard fault vectors are required.

Unfortunately, I made an incorrect assumption in my earlier answer regarding your processor.  The Cortex-M0 does not have the ability to change the offset to the vector table like the Cortex-M3 does.

So, in the case of your processor (an M0), the boot and the application utilize the same vector table when an interrupt occurs - which is defined by the boot.  So, whatever interrupts you plan on using in your application, must be defined by your boot so that they are redirected to the application's ISR's.  You do so by defining your ISR functions as re-direct functions, so that the ISR's created for your application will be called.

The example given in the application note you mention does exactly what I have described:

```
void SysTick_Handler(void) 
{ 
    /* Re-direct interrupt, get handler address from 
       application vector table */ 
    asm volatile("ldr r0, =0x203C"); 
    asm volatile("ldr r0, [r0]"); 
    asm volatile("mov pc, r0"); 
}
```

In the case above this is what happens...

1. The ISR vectors to the address of the `SysTick_Handler()` as defined by the boot.
2. The `SysTick_Handler()` redirects to the application ISR.  It does so by reading the address of the application ISR from the application's vector table.

As long as you don't enable the interrupts for your bootloader, the ISR's should function just fine in your application by using the redirects.  If you wanted to enable interrupts for your bootloader then you would have to get a little more creative.

Comment: Thanks for clear suggestions.  One item, VTOR not available on LPC1114.

Comment: Sorry about that.  I should have checked your device first.  I'll look into it some more and get back to you.

Comment: There... that should make a little more sense.

Comment: So, bootloader uses systick polling with interrupt disabled and user app uses systick with interrupt enabled.  I load user app at 0x2000 with full erase, then load bootloader with only sector erase. Start debug from bootloader and see systick polling, then after timeout, jump to user app which should run systick interrupt and allow break point in bootloader to see interrupt result- not happening yet..  Is there a way to view bootloader and user app in debug?

Comment: @user3613165, I have not tried, but you may be able to create a single image with both the boot and application that will allow you to debug both.  What I normally do is run the application in a debug mode where it is burned to the chip starting at 0x00000000.  I use a #define to make sure that I do some of the setup items that are normally accomplished with the boot (oscillator, etc.).  Then I run the application in debug mode with no boot on the device.  In this case, I would check to make sure the application's ISR is setup and functions as I intended (without the boot).

Comment: Then I would load both the application and the boot to make sure the boot properly re-directed to the application during an interrupt.

Comment: Only problem left (...I hope) when jumping to user app and enabling interrupts, end up in Default_Handler

Comment: @user3613165 That sounds like a separate question that requires debugging your implementation.  Please upvote and select this as the answer if it answered your question as written above.  When you post a new question as to why your interrupts are not functioning (and show the  sections of code where you are setting up your interrupts) I would be happy to help!

Comment: Ah,  ...not enough points yet where up-vote is enabled!  Much help though - thanks, will add vote as soon as points allow!

Comment: @user3613165 That makes sense.  I didn't know you had to have a minimum number of points to upvote.  I notice you haven't accepted answers on any of your questions yet.  For every accepted answer you get two points.